# Reading an array of strings from a file in Rust

Tags: rust, serde-json

I have the following JSON:

```json
[
    "String1",
    "String2",
    "String3"
]
```

I'm trying to read it in Rust with `serde_json` like this:

```rust
serde_json::from_str::<Vec<String>>("file_path").unwrap();
```

However, I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 1)'
```

The full stack trace isn't giving me much info. I tried converting it into a HashMap of the form `<String, Vec<String>>`, as well as using custom serializer types, and still get the same error repeatedly. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
serde_json::from_str::<Vec<String>>("file_path").unwrap();
                         //         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If that is your code as-is. then it won't work. `from_str` expects a `&str` with JSON in it, not a file path, e.g.

```rust
serde_json::from_str::<Vec<String>>(r#"["String1", "String2"]"#).unwrap();
```

Instead, open the file to get a `Read` and then use [`serde_json::from_reader`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html).

See the [example in the documentation](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/fn.from_reader.html#example) for more information.

Comment: I now feel incredibly stupid, but am very thankful you could find this obvious mistake that I was banging my head against a wall about.